# OWASP ZAP. How to use a cookie for scanning a website?

Tags: security, cookies, zap

I don't know how to use a cookie on ZAP for scanning a website, what I do is right click on the domain `Attack>Active Scan Subtree`.

I have tried that after doing a request to the website with a valid cookie (I was logged), in case ZAP takes the last cookie, but apparently it doesn't, so the result is that I have scanned just the login, not the I could have accessed when logged.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I needed, a context, doesn't work providing a cookie (which I would like too) but with the login credentials

https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartConceptsAuthentication#formBased